# Leverage browser caching - updates not working

Tags: .htaccess, web

I am using Google page speed insights to improve the performance but no matter what I do I can't get the 'leverage browser caching' to disappear.

I have modified the htaccess file as described on several online articles and added every combination I can. In page insights it's complaining about CSS/PNG/JS/JPG files.

```
# Expires Caching Start #
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 day" 
ExpiresByType text/html "access 2 day" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"  
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
# Expires Caching End #
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be missing you plus in "access plus 1 month" in many lines.
Default should be your second line for readability

Here is part of the h5bp template:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"
```

...
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Apache, you might want to run these as this worked for me:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo a2enmod expires
service apache2 restart
```

You also might want to try this code:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: That code doesn't seem much different to what I have already.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```